# spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/test] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [*/*]

Tags: spark-java

I have a Spark API and I'm trying to make POST requests. I keep getting a 404 response status and this error in my console:

> spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/test] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [*/*]

I've verified my API works for GET requests, and I've done reading of similar threads, but I seem to be having the issue still. This is what my class looks like:

```
    options("/*",
            (request, response) -> {

                String accessControlRequestHeaders = request
                        .headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
                if (accessControlRequestHeaders != null) {
                    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                            accessControlRequestHeaders);
                }

                String accessControlRequestMethod = request
                        .headers("Access-Control-Request-Method");
                if (accessControlRequestMethod != null) {
                    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                            accessControlRequestMethod);
                }

                return "OK";
            });

    before("/*", (request, response) -> response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));


    post("/test", (request, response) -> {
    response.type("application/json");
    response.status(200);

    // Here to not return a null value
    return new Gson()
      .toJson(new Color(1));
    });
```

I am testing this request from Postman. There, I have the headers as
`'Accept': 'application/json'` and a body containing `'body': 'body'` for testing purposes.

I understand that my POST method is not really doing anything that warrants it being a POST method, it's just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're defining the route `/test/` but when testing you're navigating to `/test`. These are not equal routes in Sparkjava.

If you want to make both `/test` and `/test/` have the same implementation - I'd define `/test` as my route and then redirect `/test/` to it using a [before-filter](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#filters). Something like:

```
before((request, response) -> {
  if (request.pathInfo().equals("/test/") {
    response.redirect("/test");
  }
});
```

(In reality, of course, you'd want to make this code more generic).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think this is the issue, because I've tried defining the route as both `/test` and `/test/`, and attempted to send the request to both routes. I tested it again for sanity's sake, and still a no-go. I'll edit my post to reflect this issue though, thanks

Comment: @MichaelRotuno maybe this is not the whole issue but it is *an* issue that prevents your code from running the way you expect it to, and this error would show 404. To further debug, I'd remove all `options` and `before` filters and add a log message inside the route handler to see first if you ever land there with the minimum boilerplate needed.